# jquery find a href by title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the sidemenu something like below. On clicking the href link, I'm showing the corresponding div id by href title.

```
<ul class="sidenav">
    <li><a href="#" title="sample">Sample</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="test">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I also have the next button, on clicking it, I want to highlight the href on which the current div is being shown.
So I have the id something like below,

```
var $title = $(".hidefields:visible").attr('id'); //this is the href title and hidefields is the div class 
$("a[title|= $title]").css("color", "red");..// this doesn't work.
```

How do I find the href by the variable title? I couldn't find the solution on the internet.

Comment: where it is $(".hidefields:visible") in your html

Comment: `$("a[title="+ $title +"]").css(...=`

Comment: @zvona it perfectly works..thank you. how do I give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly had it, but your `$title` gets seen as a string. So do something like:

```
$("a[title|= " + $title + "]").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector

```
$('a[title="sample"]')
```

**Your code**

```
$('a[title="' + $title '"]').css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to find it using a class attribute instead of the title. Nothing says that they can't have the same value, but jQuery is built on using classes and ids for finding nodes in the DOM.

Eg. from you question above:
HTML:

```
<ul class="sidenav">
     <li><a href="#" class="sample" title="sample">Sample</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="test" title="test">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var $title = $(".hidefields:visible").attr('id'); //this is the href title and hidefields is the div class 
$(".hidefields:visible a." + $title).css("color", "red");
```